# Automatic change table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have two table that connect each other. I want it if first table value change it will change value of second table automatically. Any **Magic Code** for this problem. 
this is my first table:

```
  First table:
      TIMESTAMP            Status
    1/29/2013 08:00          0
    1/29/2013 08:30          0
    1/29/2013 09:00          1

 Second table:
     Status                DATETIME_INPUT
        0                 1/29/2013 08:00
        0                 1/29/2013 08:30
```

First table control second table, I want every time I add input too First table, 
It will automatically change Second Table too.

For example I add last row in First Table but it not change Second Table, I want it
AUTOMATIC CHANGE

Please give some solution

Comment: You need an insert trigger.  You should look this up in the SQL Server documentation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff , I am newbie about this stuff, could you please give some example , its better if you give me some code for my problem

Comment: 1. Use a trigger as suggested.

<soapbox>
2. It is rarely good practice to let things like this happen "automatically". This seems to be a business "rule". don't let the data layer handle business rules. Just do two SQL statements.
</soapbox>

Comment: @mrunion , what do you mean with two SQL Statement?

Comment: What is the application written in? Is this a PHP/.Net/website or a desktop app. I assumed (probably incorrectly based on your question) that you had an app. Are you just updating a table in a database by hand?

Comment: @mrunion , i got my input for first table from machine, at final i want it display on web using php

Comment: Not knowing the entire process, and assuming that the first table is updated by a "machine" that you are not controlling the data inserted into a table, You'd probably need to run an update statement similar to `UPDATE 2ndTable, 1stTable SET 2ndTable.STATUS = 1stTable.STATUS WHERE 2ndTable.DATETIME_INPUT = 1stTable.TIMESTAMP`. You could also limit the updated by a date (or date range), as this query updates the ENTIRE table -- which might take a while as the table grows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very basic trigger to insert data in your second table as it gets inserted in your first table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_Update_SecondTable
ON [FirstTable]
FOR INSERT
AS
Begin
    Insert into [SecondTable] (Status, DATETIME_INPUT) 
    Select Distinct i.Status, i.TIMESTAMP
    from Inserted i
End
```

Take a look here to see some additional information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Good luck.